# Facebook page owners access to information

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

Does Facebook provide page owners with `information` about people who `like` the page?
By `information` I mean their friends list, DOB, work, etc. Is there at all a way the page owner can access that information?

Comment: No, there is of course not. Just because I like your page, doesn’t mean you have a right to my private information.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed some breakdowns (mostly by city, country, gender, age, locale), but there's no information about single users.

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#availmetrics